# Java-8 How to reuse lamba expression

Tags: lambda, java-8

Below is the method where the lambda expression is present and I want it to be used in other methods as well without duplication.

```
    public FeatureView getFeature(String featurekey) {
    Feature feature = featureRepository.findByPrimaryKey(featurekey)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new WebApplicationException(new ResponseEntity<>(
                    ServiceError.of(404, String.format(FEATURE_NOT_FOUND, featurekey)), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)));
    return Feature.getFeatureView(feature, extractFeatureStatus(feature));
}
```

Lamba Expression

```
() -> new WebApplicationException(new ResponseEntity<>(
                    ServiceError.of(404, String.format(FEATURE_NOT_FOUND, featurekey)), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if it is a supplier, just do the following:

```
Supplier<WebApplicationException> reusableSupplier = () -> new WebApplicationException(new ResponseEntity<>(
                ServiceError.of(404, String.format(FEATURE_NOT_FOUND, featurekey)), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND))
```

and reuse `reusableSupplier` where you require it.

Alternatively you can work with method references instead, where you just have a method returning the exception you want, e.g.:

```
 static WebApplicationException myReusableException() {
   return new WebApplicationException(new ResponseEntity<>(
                   ServiceError.of(404, String.format(FEATURE_NOT_FOUND, featurekey)), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
}
```

In your Optional-call you can then just write something like:

```
.orElseThrow(YourClass::myReusableException);
```

**EDIT:** in case you want to pass a variable to it I would go with the method variant and change it to the following:

```
static Supplier<WebApplicationException myReusableException(T featureKey) {
  return () -> new WebApplicationException(.... featureKey);
}
```

and use it like:

```
.orElseThrow(myReusableException(currentFeatureKey));
```

As you can see playing with the return value may lead to interesting results. You could also use `Function<T, Supplier<WebApplicationException>>`, but I think that gets messy soon. For completion I will add a `Function`-variant without returning a `Supplier`:

```
Function<T, Exception> yourReusableFunction = featureKey -> new  WebApplicationException(.... featureKey); // where T is the type of featureKey
```

Calling it:

```
.orElseThrow(() -> yourReusableFunction.apply(currentFeatureKey));
```

Comment: Thanks. how can I pass featurekey (variable) to this supplier ?

Comment: @Shoaib627 You don't pass it. You need to place the code in this answer in the same scope as `featureKey`.

Comment: @Ronald which is the right way to do it myReusableException or yourReusableFunction ?

Comment: myReusableException looks cleaner to me

Comment: it mainly depends on your code ;-) I would also go for the method-variant but only if its name gets better ;-) I use `Function` only if used as parameter or local variable, but that only in rare cases.

Comment: @Shoaib627 if you think an answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!

Answer (score 3):

Simply:

```
Supplier<Exception> excSupplier = () -> new WebApplicationException(new ResponseEntity<>(
  ServiceError.of(404, String.format(FEATURE_NOT_FOUND, featurekey)), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
```

You can then use `excSupplier` anywhere you want.

Comment: Thanks. how can I pass featurekey (variable) to this supplier ?

Answer (score 3):

Here's how t to do this, not just in this particular situation, but *generally*.

As you may know, lambda expressions can be used as values for functional interface types, like `Consumer`, `Supplier`, `Function` etc. So the first step is to figure out what type of the lambda expression is. Here, you have:

```
() -> new WebApplicationException(new ResponseEntity<>(
        ServiceError.of(404, String.format(FEATURE_NOT_FOUND, featurekey)), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND))
```

It takes no parameters and returns a `WebApplicationException`. From this, we can deduce that it is a `Supplier<WebApplicationException>`. Another example would be if you had something that takes one parameter and returns `void`, which would be a `Consumer`.

After you figure out the type, you just need to give it a name. After that, you just declare a variable with the type and the name, and initialise it with the lambda expression. In your case, this:

```
Supplier<WebApplicationException> supplier = 
    () -> new WebApplicationException(new ResponseEntity<>(
        ServiceError.of(404, String.format(FEATURE_NOT_FOUND, featurekey)), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
```

Now, you can use this new variable *in place of* the lambda. Just replace the lambda expression with whatever name you gave it. In your case, this would be:

```
Feature feature = featureRepository.findByPrimaryKey(featurekey)
        .orElseThrow(supplier);
return Feature.getFeatureView(feature, extractFeatureStatus(feature));
```